# Is my .ssh/config correct?

Tags: 16.04, server, ssh, git, gitlab

I'm trying to connect to ubuntu 16.04 local development server from a different ip through ssh, the server has gitlab and has a public hostname. `example.com/2222`. My gitlab ssh port is `9409`

my `.ssh/config`

```
Host server
    ProxyCommand ssh -W example.com:2222 username@server
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Now to clone

`git clone ssh://server:9409/username/test.git`

It says

```
Cloning into 'test'...
Bad owner or permissions on /.ssh/config
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Also is `-W` needed in my case? I still don't know what `ssh -W` does

Edit:

I did `chmod 600` now I get `ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host`

I still think my config file has a problem somewhere

Comment: duplicate of https://serverfault.com/questions/253313/ssh-returns-bad-owner-or-permissions-on-ssh-config

Comment: It's not even going to read your config if it has bad permissions. The contents are irrelevant until those are fixed.

Comment: @SimonB please read my edit

Comment: @muru please read my edit

Comment: Ok. If your Gitlab ssh port is 9049, why are you using 2222 in your `ProxyCommand`?

Comment: @muru `2222` is the only port publicly available. you can only connect to gitlab if you are on the local network. However I tried your suggestion, still does not work

Comment: Please clarify: the ssh port and name of the Gitlab server, the ssh port and name of the bastion server

Comment: @muru gitlab is running on a local server called zoltan on port `9049`, `zoltan:9049/` Our router company gave us a domain name `example.com`, we opened port `2222` to the web. So we could tunnel through it or whatever

Comment: @Lynob so you have ssh running on port 2222 on `example.com`, and `example.com` is able to access port 9049 on `zoltan`, which has Gitlab's SSH listening on it?

Comment: @muru yes true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the clarifications, let me first note that there are three possibly different usernames involved here:

1. The username for `example.com`, say `user1`.
2. The username registered on Gitlab, which may or may not be the same as the one above, say `user2`. This is the Gitlab account for which you added the public key, for example.
3. The username for Gitlab's SSH access, which is probably `git`, and almost certainly not the username registered inside Gitlab. This depends on Gitlab's configuration.

Given that, I think this is how your ssh config should look:

```
Host  zoltan
  Port 9049
  ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p -p 2222 user1@example.com
```

And for cloning, you should do:

```
 git clone git@zoltan:user2/project.git
```

The `IdentityFile` you're specifying is used by default anyway, so that can be omitted unless there are other conflicting settings in your SSH config.